# asio - Wait for async operations to finish

Tags: c++, asynchronous, boost-asio

I am using boost.asio and I have a simple server that needs to handle multiple connections. Before starting the "connected" status, I need to perform a handshake with the client in a limited amount of time. I am using chained asynchronous operations for each step of the handshake as I need to use a timer and (as far as I know I can't do that with synchronous reads and writes). I need a way to block each connection until the deadline timer ends or the handshake succeeds, without blocking the server.

Is there any way to achieve this?

**UPDATE** Some code to clarify things

A simple server

```
typedef boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket    sock;

class server
{
public:
    server() : _ios(), _acceptor(_ios)
    {
        boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver  resolver(_ios);
        boost::asio::ip::tcp::endpoint  endpoint(boost::asio::ip::tcp::v4(), PORT);

        _acceptor.open(endpoint.protocol());
        _acceptor.set_option(boost::asio::ip::tcp::acceptor::reuse_address(true));
        _acceptor.bind(endpoint);
        _acceptor.listen();

        do_accept();
    }

    void run()
    {
        _ios.run();
    }

private:
    void do_accept()
    {
        auto socket = std::make_shared<TSock>(_ios);
        _acceptor.async_accept(*socket, std::bind(&server::handle_accept,
                                                  this, socket, std::placeholders::_1));
    }

    void handle_accept(std::shared_ptr<sock> socket, const boost::system::error_code& ec)
    {
        auto connection = std::make_shared<CCon>();

        if (connection->Accept(socket))
        {
            std::cout << "Connection accepted" << std::endl;
        }
        else
        {
            std::cout << "Connection not accepted" << std::endl;
        }

        do_accept();
    }

    boost::asio::io_service         _ios;
    boost::asio::ip::tcp::acceptor  _acceptor;

    std::set<std::shared_ptr<CCon>> _connections;
};

int32_t main(int32_t argc, char *argv[])
{
    server s;
    s.run();
}
```

**connection->Accept(socket)** explained

```
bool CCon::Accept(<std::shared_ptr<sock>> tcpSocket)
{
    // set handshake sequence
    SendGreeting();

    // I NEED TO WAIT HERE UNTIL connectionAccepted gets a value

    if (connectionAccepted)
    {
        // Connection Accepted
        return(true)
    }
    else
    {
        //Connection Rejected
        return(false)
    }
}
```

**SendGreeting()** contains

```
boost::asio::async_write(*tcpSocket, 
                         boost::asio::buffer(oBuff,bytesBuffered),
                         std::bind(&CCon::WaitForResp, 
                                   this, std::placeholders::_1));
```

The problem is that WaitForResp never gets called. It only gets called if I restart the `io_service` (`stop()` -> `reset()` -> `run()`) after setting the new handler, which isn't a solution at all.

I think I am missing something about Asio and I'd be glad if anyone could help me with it.

Comment: I need to use asynchronous functions because I need a timer for the handshake but I also need to wait (block) in a part of my code for the handshake to finish or the timer to end.

Comment: I've tried using futures but, somehow, the handshake gets stuck in the first handler until `future` finishes its waiting time, then all the handshake runs  (maybe I need to have the io_service running in another thread?). I need some time to simplify my code and post it here but I will do it to make it clear.

Comment: @TechnikEmpire I added some code. I hope it's clearer now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your example code isn't complete, so I can't guarantee my answer is a solution, but I'll point out a few things that I think are the problem.

Point 1 - The `io_service` doesn't just keep running. If it thinks there's no more work to be done (nothing in the cue), then `::run()` will exit, and since you're expecting it not to, you're going to get unexpected behavior. You need to prevent it from running out of work, by creating and keeping an `io_service::work` object alive. From the docs:

```
boost::asio::io_service io_service;
boost::asio::io_service::work work(io_service);
...
```

More on that [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_59_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/io_service.html#boost_asio.reference.io_service.stopping_the_io_service_from_running_out_of_work).

Secondly, I'm concerned about how the `CCon` object lifetime is maintained. Who is responsible for keeping it alive? I ask because you're binding to `this` inside of it, so you're spawning async callbacks internally but apparently relying on an external object to make sure that `this` is alive if and when the callback returns. If you're failing to do this correctly, you're going to get undefined behavior, which doesn't necessarily mean that you're going to get a big crash and error code, but maybe somehow the handler completes or hangs forever, or some other strange inconclusive behavior because of the undefined state.

Based on the incomplete code here, it looks like nothing is keeping `CCon` alive externally, which means that things are probably falling out of scope and getting destroyed. I'm going to guess that you always get "connection not accepted" in your server, if anything at all. If you break down the code you have here, you spawn a `CCon` wrapped in a `shared_ptr`, then call `::Accept()`, which in turn invokes **non-blocking** async methods which may complete immediately, or 100 years from now. Since they're **non-blocking**, the code is going to step into the `if(connectionAccepted)` statement immediately and therefore return one way another immediately, at which time your `shared_ptr` of `CCon` falls out of scope in the server `handle_accept`, the ref count gets decremented to 0 and the destructor is invoked.

What you should be doing is making `CCon` inherit from `std::enable_shared_from_this` or `boost::enable_shared_from_this` and in all of the async callbacks that `CCon` binds internally, you should bind to `shared_from_this()`, which will feed another `shared_ptr` into the cue from the bind, incrementing the ref count of your shared `CCon` object and guaranteeing the lifetime of `CCon` to at least extend into the completion handler.

Third, I think your design approach isn't the best solution, as a side note. You shouldn't be forcing every other possible incoming connection to wait for the previous connection to go through some authentication process. You're holding up the acceptor from doing its job for new clients until the previous client goes does some talking with the server. That's a completely unnecessary bottleneck.

I believe you're doing this because you want to, at the `::server` object level, determine if clients have properly passed the authentication process. You should instead just pass a function or something to the `CCon::Accept(...)` method which it can invoke to report things to the server, if you really need the server to know anything at all. Copy the asio model and change your `Accept` method to `AsyncAccept`, make it non-blocking and give it a callback for when it completes, at which time you can check its final state.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but: 1- `work` may be not necessary here as I call `do_accept()` at the end of the `handle_accept()` so the `io_service` has always something to do, like [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_59_0/doc/html/boost_asio/example/cpp11/http/server/server.cpp). 2 - Thanks for your advice, you are completely right about it, but after changing this, the behaviour of the server is still the same..., it is not the cause that is causing me problems.

Comment: @Bituki Did you see the part about properly binding to `shared_from_this` inside of `CCon`? Because from the code you've posted, your `shared_ptr` of `CCon` is going to fall out of scope very quickly and the destructor is going to be invoked. Print "destroyed" to the console in `~CCon` to verify.

Comment: Yes, I said in my second point that I applied your advice, but it didn't solve my problem.

Comment: Oh I see it now. Well I'm at a loss, I think you'll need to post complete code for me to actually build and test, because those are the only problems I can see from what's here.

Comment: Sorry, my fault. I missed to replace one `this` in my code. Now it seems to be working. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Bituki Cool, glad I could help! Welcome to SO by the way. :)